# Prove inequality with probability

Tags: probability, inequality

Assume $EX=\mu $ and $VarX=\sigma^2$.
Prove that $$Pr[|X-\mu|\geq \epsilon\mu] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$$

From Chebyshev's inequality I get
$$Pr[|X-\mu|\geq \epsilon\mu] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2\mu^2}$$
If $\mu$ is greater than $1$ than I'm done, beacuse $\frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2\mu^2} \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$ but I don't know anything about $\mu$.
Am I missing something?

Comment: The inequality you are trying to prove is incorrect.

Comment: There could be a typo and perhaps they just wanted $P(|X-\mu|\geq \epsilon)$. This is why it is important to give context to your problem. Where did you encounter it?What were you originally trying to prove or study etc.

Comment: A typo is very probable... I will ask my professor, I'm doing some exercises in advance to the lecture to get a better grasp of it (this inequality will be needed in one of the proofs, left to check for students). Thanks, I'll find out if there is a typo.